# Angular fetch data from back-end in separate thread

Tags: angular, spring-boot, user-experience

Here's the scenario :
In two pages : home page and list data page.in order to improve the user experience, in home page, when the user click a button, i have to launch a separate thread in which i fetch data (data are for list data page) from restful api, when data are fetched, i want to show a notification to the user saying that data are ready and he can go to list data page. Due to heavy amount of data, it's not to good to redirect the user to list data page and wait for data to be fetched from back-end.
I use angular fir front-end and springboot for back-end.
Note : i have implemented a solution using async functions.. But i need a solution for the described scenario.

Comment: javascript is single threaded. you can use a web worker maybe but it sounds like the problem is you're fetching too much data at once and need to implement pagination

Answer (score 0):

In Angular, and in general in JavaScript, don't think in terms of threads.

What you are describing can be achieved using an Angular service and some Promises:

1. Create an Angular Service `MyService` that will use [HttpClient](https://angular.io/guide/http) to expose a method `getMyData`. Inside of that method, use the `HttpClient.doGet` to get the data you want. Once the data is fetched, cache it in this service. Also return a Promise so the invoker knows when the data is ready. Something like this:

```js
public getMyData() {
    return this.httpClient.doGet("http://example.com/my-endpoint")
               .toPromise()
               .then(data => this.cachedData = data)
}

public getMyCachedData() {
    return this.cachedData;
}
```

2. In your HomePage component, invoke `MyService.getMyData` and use the `then` method of the returned Promise to set a flag `isDataReady` to `true`. Something like this:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getMyData()
                  .then(data => this.isDataReady = true)
}
```

3. In the template of HomePage, whenever `isDataReady` is set to true, display the message telling the user the data is ready. This message should provide a link to the ListPage:

```html
    <a *ngIf="isDataReady" routerLink="/list-page">Data is ready</a>
```

4. In ListPage, retrieve the cached data from the service:

```js
ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.getMyCachedData()
                  .then(data => /* do something with your data */)
}
```

There is more information about using a service to communicate components in the [Angular Guide](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service).